# I'm using a Thread and when i left the Fragment, the app closes

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

I'm using a Thread in my fragment for update the Time that i'm showing in a TextView. But when i change of fragment, my app closes. I believe that the Thread continue running after i left the fragment. I have tried to use the `Thread.interrupt()` in method `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` but i couldn't solve.

fragmentTime.java (without `Thread.interrupt()`)

```
public class EventosFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView currentTime;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_eventos, container, false);

        currentTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.currentTime);

        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateTime();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();

        return v;
    }

    public void updateTime() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        Date parsed = null; // => Date is in UTC now
        try {
            parsed = sourceFormat.parse(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        currentTime.setText(sourceFormat.format(parsed));
    }

}
```

[image]

fragmentTime.java (with `Thread.interrupt()`)

```
public class EventosFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView currentTime;
    Thread timer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_eventos, container, false);

        currentTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.currentTime);

        timer = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateTime();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        timer.interrupt();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        timer.start();
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        timer.interrupt();
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void updateTime() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        Date parsed = null; // => Date is in UTC now
        try {
            parsed = sourceFormat.parse(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        currentTime.setText(sourceFormat.format(parsed));
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs that might suggest why the app is closing, do you see an exception? I was wondering if it might be related to something else.

Comment: I returned the code to the initial form and i see this fatal exception @CarlPoole

Comment: where are you calling Thread.interrupt()?

Comment: @pablobu I put in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getActivity` is returning `null` because the Fragment is no longer attached to an Activity.

You can resolve the problem by stopping the timer in `Fragment.onDetach`.

Comment: Ok, but how i can resolve it? I tried in the form that i said and i didn't have success.

Comment: Oh, now i understand... I was thinking that when i change the fragment, he just stops and isn't destroied.

Comment: Yep!  you got it!  :thumbsup: